# Can I assume counterfeit components?

Tags: components, pcb-assembly, manufacturing

I recently received a run of 10 PCBs from a manufacturer in China, and am worried they have begun to cut corners and source counterfeit parts. Here is why:

I had them do full turnkey production (PCB Fab, component procurement, assembly). I've used them in the past and they've been pretty good, albeit with an occasional mistake.

I noticed on 4 / 10 boards, the circuit below not behaving as expected:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0ZC4C.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

On the faulty boards, whereas we expect the gate voltages of Q3 + Q5 to be either ~0 V (if NOR output = 1 (5V)) or ~12 V (if NOR output = 0 (GND)), the gate voltages were anywhere from 3-7 V...

Here is why I'm suspicious of the parts:

1. We've used this exact circuit in previous iterations of the PCB, with the same manufacturer, and haven't seen this issue. Only changes are minor difference in PCB layout.
2. After I hand-removed Q1 Q3 and Q5, and replaced them with parts I had from Digikey, the circuit functions as expected. I've done this on 3 boards, and all 3 went from non-working to working.

The relevant NPN + PMOS part numbers are given below, here are datasheet links:
[DMP3010](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/DMP3010LK3.pdf)
[MBT2222](http://www.mccsemi.com/up_pdf/MMBT2222A(SOT-23).pdf)

Alternatively if something seems fundamentally wrong with the circuit, I'm all ears. But it is a pretty common, simple circuit, and as mentioned one I've used in previous iterations with no problem.

Comment: You did the wrong thing in replacing all three components. Know you don't know which of the three is the true fault. Assuming even if they used fake FETs  and that they are still insulated gate FET devices, it would seem more likely that the Q1 is your problem.    Your R1 value is rather high (10k) so I'd imagine the most likely problem is that the Q1 leakage is high. This might be caused by overheating during soldering and perhaps they have a PCB reflow problem and are hand soldering as touchup/repair.

Comment: 10 boards may be hand assembled depending on complexity, may just be human error in placement / soldering

Comment: Likely ESD causing gate leakage on either FET or both. (Bipolar transistors are pretty tough in comparison). On the next faulty board, isolate both source and drain from anything (unplug supply, load) and measure leakage from each FET to gate. So probably poor assembly rather than poor purchasing, though both are possible.

Comment: @JackCreasey thanks for the response. Although I don't have a lot of data points to use, I did try yesterday on the board to replace ONLY Q1 (BJT). Q3 + Q5's gate, with the new Q1 was still approximately 3.5 V. Then, I replaced only Q3 (12V PMOS) and the gate voltage was still stuck around 3.5V. Lastly, I replaced Q5 (5V PMOS), and re-replaced Q1 (with another BJT from the same reel from Digikey, to be safe) and all voltages were as expected.

Comment: @JackCreasey I suppose before I replaced Q1 (NPN) the second time, I should have tested with the new Q1 Q3 and Q5, but given that both the 1st and 2nd replacement for Q1 were from the same reel, I think they can be considered equivalent.

Comment: @sstobbe have any recommendations for how I could test this, whether visually, electrically, or with a meter?

Comment: @BrianDrummond I'll do this on the next board I get that I see this effect on before making any other changes, thanks.

Comment: Do you have any kind of test fixture to generate performance graphs of the components? If you can consistently find deviations from properly sourced parts, they are counterfeit. If they just behave like broken components, they are broken components.

Comment: @Jim yes visual/continuity/resistance etc. Note your design has a power sequencing requirement of 12V before 5V otherwise the gate pull-up voltage is undefined and may half turn on Q5 causing it to burn up

Comment: @Jim. When you next have a faulty board with this type of fault ...  1) Short Q1 collector to ground ...if the output switches turn on then they are functioning ok. 2) if Q1 collector does not rise to 12 v, remove Q1. If the voltage rises to 12 V Q1 is leaking, if the voltage on R1/Q1 collector track does not rise, then Q3 or Q5 is bad.  I'd also suggest you need to change the value of R1 to about 1-3k Ohm in future builds.

Comment: (1) On board with "bad" gate voltage remove Q1 or disconnect collector. (a) If Vgates rises to 12V issue is with drive. (b) If Vgates remains about the same issue is with FETS.  (2) Id 1b then place 1K across R1 (a) If voltage changes minimally you may have zener action as Spehro suggests. (b) ...
(3) Measure gs junction of Q3 Q5 to ensure they are FETS and not now bipolars. (4) Test Spehro's zener on gate theory - if so you'll see a High V fwd diode when Vgs is positive (FET off) (say 1V-1V5) and a zener of ?V when Vgs is negative (FET on).

Answer (score 11):

You have to prove the parts are bad.  They may be damaged by ESD.

If you had only pulled the Q5 or Q3 and measured V(Q1-C), that would have isolated the part as the problem.  Then verify R1 is 10k and not 10M or something else.

The only weakness on the design is that the circuit turn off is slow and load reactance is unknown.

**Normally any FET** *(such as this one rated for 8mΩ @ VGS = -10V)*  **is driven by a gate driver resistance of about 1000x** *(8Ω as used in datasheet)* but your **R1/RdsOn ratio is about 10 million.** This makes it slow and prone to oscillations with stray inductive/capacitive feedback to gate voltage depending on layout.

- also you are putting ~(4V-0.7)/1k=3.3mA into base and and capable of driving >>100mA into gate capacitance Ciss, until Vce is saturated. But pullup to turn off is only 12V/10k = 1.2mA which results in spurious turn off behavior.  More design margin would use 1k for R1 at most.

### Conclusion:

Test FETs for ESD damage, leakage in gate as per above. Reduce R1.

There is no assumption as to if/when the ESD damage occurred.

### Article on Clone parts.

http://www.sae.org/aaqg/audit_information/2010/Atlanta/Impact%20of%20Counterfeit%20Parts%20NASA.pdf

Comment: Thanks Tony. I used a higher R1 to minimize power consumption, and because switching speed isn't a performance requirement for us; this is a reset switch used for a few seconds every few hours. However, I didn't consider the protection aspect. I'll have to take closer look with the scope.

Answer (score 8):

I suspect they may have substituted a MOSFET that has low voltage gate protection zeners for the DI parts. There is no motivation to sub Q1, they're dirt cheap in China and any similar part would work as well. The MOSFETs, on the other hand, are expensive.

Your circuit switches off slowly so it could put a lot of stress on the MOSFETs if the loads are low impedance, but that would not likely cause the observed effect (though it could conceivably under some conditions).

If you have another misbehaving board try swapping out just Q3 if you want test my theory. You can also contact DI with a high quality photo of the part markings and ask them if they match parts made for sale anywhere in the world. Of course you can compare them visually with the parts you bought through distribution but there are often multiple packaging facilities used and the markings may vary somewhat, especially (but not exclusively) for very different date codes, so a difference is not conclusive. If they look exactly (**to a critical eye**) the same including method of marking, font, and small features on the transfer molding, it's a pretty good indication the parts came out the same factory.

For such a tiny quantity they probably sent someone down to the market (in Shenzhen at Huaqiang bei lu) and got whatever parts were available from one of the many retail vendors. If you want to be 100% sure, send your own parts to them, especially if the quantities are modest).

Comment: Great advice. A couple follow up questions: 1. what would you consider low impedance in this context? The 5 V Fet is switching anywhere from 25-750 mA, the 12 V FET from 100 mA - 5 A..... 2. I think I'll follow up with DI.  3. Good thinking regarding sending our own parts; we've done this in the past and haven't seen the issue.

Comment: Given that I haven't gotten to the root of the problem yet, should I consider this problem unanswered? Both you and @Tony gave great, actionable advice but I don't know for sure at this point.

Comment: If the power dissipation in the MOSFET is excessive during the switching. From what you say about I doubt it's a problem. You can select whichever answer is more helpful or none at all, or defer and do it later. It's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

I bet you do have a parts issue, However the issue is likely due to your MBT2222. A widely used generic N2222a transistor is likely being swaped and that has been  fabricated by hundreds of manufacturers  to who knows what specifications .